# How to register Post Submit handler for form?

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

I have a form which I want to modify some of it's data after submission.

I'm using drupal 8.3 and I tried to used `hook_form_alter` and registered my functions to `$form['#submit'][]` and `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][]`  but none of them working after form submission.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Is the code being hit? Have you debugged it?

Comment: nah it doesn't hit.

Comment: Need to see all the code

Comment: you need your code after the form submit?

Answer (score 0):

I added the following snippet in `hook_form_alter`:

```
array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'callback');
foreach ($form['actions'] as $action => $values) {
    if (isset($form['actions'][$action]['#submit']) && is_array($form['actions'][$action]['#submit'])) {
        if (!in_array('callback',$form['actions'][$action]['#submit'])) {
            array_unshift($form['actions'][$action]['#submit'], 'callback');
        }
    }
}
```

This registers to all actions.

Comment: Note that if you are not limiting by a `$form_id`, this code will happen for every form in the site (front end and backend) upon submission.

Comment: That, also in 8.4.x, this will no longer be necessary as the dropbutton save pattern has been removed from node forms, it now uses a published checkbox + a single save button.

Answer (score 0):

you did n't mention  you are tring that custom submit  handler to  core forms or your custom  form....

If it is  core form  use this hook
hook_form_FORM_ID_alter
  and replace form id for your form and   try to print the form in the hook .......
 Echo "pre";
Print_r($form) ; 
By printing you can know the structure of the submit  button array format......and add ur custom  submit handler in the same way and print your function whether it is added or not

If its  custom form then  add the same in the build form structure submit button code